Must I follow suit and stand for Kiddush?
There are different customs whether to stand or sit during Kiddush. Even those who stand for all/part of Friday Night Kiddush, many sit for the Shabbos Day Kiddush.
I have observed a common trend to imitate the person making Kiddush. People who would stand when they make Kiddush will sit when the mekadesh is sitting; people who usually sit will stand when the mekadesh is standing.
The concept of sitting when the mekadesh is sitting, I believe is based on Tosafos (Berachos 43), that a form of kevius is necessary for listeners to fulfil their obligation through the public recital of the mekadesh. This idea is mentioned by Mishnah Berurah (271:46):

ויותר טוב לישב – דבכי האי גוונא מקרי טפי קידוש במקום סעודה כיון שיושב
במקום סעודתו בעת הקידוש. וכן הסכים בבאור הגר״א ומטעם אחר, דכיון שאחד
פוטר חברו בעינן קביעות שיקבעו יחד ובישיבה מקרי קביעות וכנ״ל בסימן קס״ז
ולפי דבריו גם השומעים צריכין לישב וטוב ליזהר בזה לכתחלה

However, I could not find any real source for standing because the mekadesh is standing. The closest I could find to a 'source' was this ruling on shulchanaruchharav.com written by a [unknown to me!] Rabbi Yaakov Goldstein:

Whether the listeners are to stand or sit during Kiddush follows the
same ruling as the person making Kiddush. Practically, the custom
is to stand if the person making Kiddush is standing, although if he
is sitting, one can choose to stand or sit.

Although most rulings on this site cite sources in the footnotes, this specific ruling is unsourced.
Does this custom/ruling have any halachic basis?

I'll accept an answer that either finds a primary source for this custom, or a halachic source disproving this custom.

This is not a duplicate of this question, which focuses on the general obligation to stand or sit during Kiddush. I am specifically looking for source of custom to stand when mekadesh is standing.

Is this not just מנהג המקום and אל ישנה מפני המחלוקת. Just like kedusha in a shul of a different nusach

The custom quoted from shulchanaruchharav.com was only by standing. He claims that when the person making kiddush is sitting, the listener may choose. Seemingly, it isn't just minhag hamakom.

@DoubleAA: When there is no established minhag hamakom, but someone who decided to make Kiddush for some friends stands because his father did, does this constitute מנהג המקום?

That's a question on shulchanaruchharav.com. The normal principles of אל ישנה and לא תתגודדו are clearly at play.
